# Send list of files using socket wifip2p

Tags: android, sockets, wifip2p

I'm trying to send multiple files from client to server using socket but when I click upload button it adds only one file second

Comment: What statement exactly is throwing the error? Client side or server side? What does `CopyFile.copyFile()` look like exactly?

Comment: server side code is showing error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your `copyFile()` is not suitable for network transmissions.

You need to get rid of the two `close()` calls inside of `copyFile()`. On the client side, `out.close()` is closing the socket after the 1st file has been sent. On the server side, `InputStream.close()` is closing the socket after the 1st file has been received. It is the caller's responsibility to close the streams it passes to `copyFile()`, it is not `copyFile()`'s responsibility.

More importantly, for each file the client wants to send, `copyFile()` is not sending the file's byte count before sending the file's actual bytes, to indicate where each file ends and the next begins. So, on the server side, `copyFile()` does not know when to stop reading from the `inputStream` and will just keep reading endlessly until the connection is closed/broken.

As-is, `copyFile()` may work for copying files from one folder to another on the local system, but it is not suitable for copying files over a TCP network.

Try this instead:

Client side:

```java
try {
    socket.bind(null);
    socket.connect((new InetSocketAddress(host, port)), SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
    Log.d(TAG, "Client socket - " + socket.isConnected());

    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
    dos.writeInt(fileUri.size());

    for(String file : fileUri)
    {
        //long length = file.length();
        //dos.writeLong(length);

        String name = file;
        dos.writeUTF(name);

        File f = new File(file);
        sendFile(f, dos);
    }

    dos.close();
    Log.d(TAG, "Client: Data written");
}
catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
}
finally {
    if (socket != null) {
        if (socket.isConnected()) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                // Give up
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```java
void sendFile(File in, DataOutputStream out) throws IOException {

    long fileLength = in.length();
    out.writeLong(fileLength);

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(in);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

    byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
    int len;

    while (fileLength > 0) {
        len = bis.read(buf);
        if (len == -1) throw new IOException();
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
        fileLength -= len;
    }
}
```

Server side:

```java
try {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8988);

    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream());
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

    int filesCount = dis.readInt();
    File[] files = new File[filesCount];

    for(int i = 0; i < filesCount; i++)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: " + filesCount);
        //long fileLength = dis.readLong();
        String fileName = dis.readUTF();

        files[i] = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir("received"), Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".mp4" );
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: 1" );
        File dirs = new File(context.getPackageName() + files[i].getParent());
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: 2" );
        if (!dirs.exists()) dirs.mkdirs();
        files[i].createNewFile();
        Log.d(TAG, "server: copying files " + files[i].toString());

        receiveFile(dis, files[i]);
    }
    serverSocket.close();
    return "done";
}
catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    return null;
}
```

```java
void receiveFile(DataInputStream in, File out) throws IOException {

    long fileLength = in.readLong();

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(out);
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

    byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
    int len;

    while (fileLength > 0) {
        len = (fileLength >= 1024) ? 1024 : (int) fileLength;
        len = in.read(buf, 0, len);
        if (len == -1) throw new IOException();
        bos.write(buf, 0, len);
        fileLength -= len;
    }
}
```

Comment: An error occurred while executing doInBackground() at android.Os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)

Comment: FileServerAsyncTask class is throwing an error after first file transfered.

Comment: receivefile function makes the size of file large : for example when i send 20 mb video , receivefile function makes it of 100 mb please tell me how to over come those problems

Comment: @AbhiShekKamboj The code I gave you DOES NOT expand the file sizes, so your issue has to be an error in the way you applied my code to your project. Please edit your question to include a [mcve] showing everything you are actually doing.

Comment: Sir : if(len == -1) throw new IOException()  of receivefile function is throwing error  once a first file transferred

Comment: @AbhiShekKamboj sorry my bad, I was not decrementing `fileLength` after `bos.write()`, so the loop was not exiting at the end of the 1st file. I have updated the code to fix that.

Comment: sir its working  and  thank you so much for helping me